# What is wrong with my Oracle SQL statement? I keep getting a column not allowed here error?

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, ora-00984

Okay, so what is wrong with my SQL*Plus statement? As far as I can tell everything should be working?

```
   //get parameters from the request
 String custID=request.getParameter("cust_ID");
 String saleID=request.getParameter("sale_ID");
 String firstName=request.getParameter("first_Name");
 String mInitial=request.getParameter("mI");
 String lastName=request.getParameter("last_Name");
 String streetName=request.getParameter("street");
 String city=request.getParameter("city");
 String state=request.getParameter("state");
 String zipCode=request.getParameter("zip_Code");
 String DOB=request.getParameter("DOB");
 String agentID=request.getParameter("agent_ID");
 String homePhone=request.getParameter("home_Phone");
 String cellPhone=request.getParameter("cell_Phone");
 String profession=request.getParameter("profession");
 String employer=request.getParameter("emoployer");
 String referrer=request.getParameter("referrer");

 stmt.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO customer 
                         (cust_ID, sale_ID, first_Name, mI, last_Name, street_Name, city, state, zip_Code, DOB, agent_ID, home_Phone, cell_Phone, profession, employer, referrer)"
                    + " VALUES 
                         (custID, saleID, firstName, mInitial, lastName, streetName, city, state, zipCode, DOB, agentID, homePhone, cellPhone, profession, employer, referrer)");
```

SQL DDL

```
   CREATE TABLE customer
       (cust_ID     NUMBER          NOT NULL,
        sale_ID             NUMBER          NOT NULL,
        first_Name      VARCHAR2(30)        NOT NULL,
        mI          VARCHAR2(2)         ,
        last_Name       VARCHAR2(50)        NOT NULL,
        street_Name     VARCHAR2(50)        NOT NULL,
        city            VARCHAR2(30)        NOT NULL,
        state           VARCHAR2(2)     NOT NULL,
        zip_Code        VARCHAR2(5)     NOT NULL,
        DOB         DATE            ,
        agent_ID        NUMBER              ,
        home_Phone      VARCHAR2(12)        UNIQUE,         
        cell_Phone      VARCHAR2(12)        UNIQUE,
        profession      VARCHAR2(30)            ,
        employer        VARCHAR2(30)            ,
        referrer        VARCHAR2(30)            
     );
```

SQL DML

```
INSERT INTO customer 
VALUES (primary_ID.nextval,17,'Kito','M','Bradford','123 DeLancy Lane','Wabash','TX','12345','01-JAN-69',1,'222-222-2222','301-555-6874','software engineer','HPL', NULL);

INSERT INTO customer 
VALUES (primary_ID.nextval,18,'Morpheus',' ','Smith','1289 Matrix Lane','Idaho', 'NE', '45678','06-JUN-72',2,'321-654-9877','258-852-9635','doctor', 'The OC', NULL);

SELECT * FROM customer;
```

Comment: SQLPlus is the app you use for command line access to an Oracle database.

Comment: Yeah, the SQL DDL and DDL is what I actually entered at the SQL prompt in order to set up the database.  I included it just in case anyone wanted to double check them based on the jsp that is not working.  I am getting a column not allowed here error?  All the columns seem correct. . . I dont know what is wrong with this thing. Driving me crazy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are not inserting the values of the variables. You are inserting variable names.

Replace

```
stmt.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO customer 
                         (cust_ID, sale_ID, first_Name, mI, last_Name, street_Name, city, state, zip_Code, DOB, agent_ID, home_Phone, cell_Phone, profession, employer, referrer)"
                    + " VALUES 
                         (custID, saleID, firstName, mInitial, lastName, streetName, city, state, zipCode, DOB, agentID, homePhone, cellPhone, profession, employer, referrer)");
```

by

```
preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO customer 
                         (cust_ID, sale_ID, first_Name, mI, last_Name, street_Name, city, state, zip_Code, DOB, agent_ID, home_Phone, cell_Phone, profession, employer, referrer)"
                    + " VALUES 
                         (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
preparedStatement.setLong(1, Long.valueOf(custID));
preparedStatement.setLong(2, Long.valueOf(saleID));
preparedStatement.setString(3, firstName);
// ...
preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
```

Please note that you shouldn't use string concatenation `+` to glue the variables together in a SQL string. It would be totally open to [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks. Use `PreparedStatement` all the way.

Comment: I think that did it; however, I get a general "unknown error".  We are having problems with our Oracle server. It has been going in and out all day. I think that is where this new "unknown error" is coming from.  Thanks for the assist and new PreparedStatement class/type that I will use from now on:)